# T-SQL - Parse multiple values into multiple rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, cross-apply

I know there are a lot of questions about parsing JSON objects into multiple rows - but I'm working with a column that doesn't contain actual JSON, but rather a string that is already pre-extracted from a JSON array.

My table looks like this:

| ID | Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | ["abc"] |
| 5678 | ["def","hij"] |
| 9999 | ["klm","nop","qrs"] |

Where each Group_ID can contain a potentially unlimited number of values (each value in quotes)

How can I convert the above table into something like this (where each Group_ID has it's own row):

| ID | Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | abc |
| 5678 | def |
| 5678 | hij |
| 9999 | klm |
| 9999 | nop |
| 9999 | qrs |

Comment: Hopefully the purpose here is this is to actually fix this **broken schema** you're stuck with now, and not just an attempt to process the data within the larger application.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Curious what you mean by that... Are you just saying the best option would be to parse the data prior to when it makes it into SQL server? This data is coming from a REST API and during some ETL jobs is inserted to SQL in this format, but theoretically I can modify those ETL jobs, but my thinking is if SQL can handle it why not take the path of least resistance...

Comment: Yes, you should parse it before insertion. I'm not entirely against storing json data in a database in some circumstances if that's what you're given, but you should have defined schema around anything you might need to query against and extract those fields from the json at insert time. Also, it's pretty much **never** a good idea to store array data in a single field, in any format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sql server 2016+ you can still use the [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
    (
        [ID] INT
      , [Group_ID] NVARCHAR(255)
    );

INSERT INTO @testdata (
                          [ID]
                        , [Group_ID]
                      )
VALUES ( 1234, '["abc"]' )
     , ( 5678, '["def","hij"]' )
     , ( 9999, '["klm","nop","qrs"]' );


SELECT      [ID]
          , [Value] AS [Group_ID]
FROM        @testdata
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Group_ID]);
```

Giving results of:

```
ID          Group_ID
----------- ----------
1234        abc
5678        def
5678        hij
9999        klm
9999        nop
9999        qrs
```

Comment: This is definitely much cleaner than `STRING_SPLIT()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split` to easily get your rows as follows:

```
select t.Id, s.value Group_Id
from t
cross apply String_Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(group_id,'"',''),'[',''),']',''),',')s
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming square brackets and double quotes can't ever sneak into the data, we can cheat using `PARSENAME()` which will extract the contents between either of those delimiters:

```
SELECT w.ID, Group_ID = PARSENAME(f.value, 1)
  FROM dbo.what AS w 
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(PARSENAME(w.group_id, 1), ',') AS f;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=22320c3ef0fb3905cc31085d3ab8ebc6)